# C ; operator usage

Tags: c, operators

While I was writing code,C compiler (GCC in my case) doesn't give error or warning when using ; operator repeatedly like

```
int main()
{
  ;
  ;
  ;
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

It is obvious that for loop can be implemented without giving any input

```
for(;;)
{ /* Some implementations */
}
```

but when it comes to while loop, Compiler throws an error.

```
while()
{
}
```

So is it possible to explain what does actually ; operator do in C and why it does not give an error when it is put nothing before ;?

Comment: `but when it comes to while loop, Compiler throws an error.` - because that's not a valid syntax.

Comment: For us to explain why your `while` loop doesn't work, you'll have to show us your `while` loop.

Comment: in case of `for (;;)` - that's a spec approved format.

Comment: My guess is that you're not providing your `while` loop a condition.

Comment: ... and my guess was right.  Not to be glib, but `for(;;)` works because the language allows it, and `while()` doesn't work because the language doesn't allow it.  Try `while(true)` or `while(1)`.

Comment: I added while loop too. Since for loop takes 3 arguments with 2 ; operator, while does not have to take one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so it is because the language allows it? what happening behind when ; operator is put repeatedly, is it ignored by compiler? I really want to learn.

Comment: You seem to have this belief that semicolons (or any other element in programming languages) should work the same way in every case.  They don't.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to think of it this way: in your `for` loop, semicolons separate the parts, and each part is optional.  In a while loop, there are not multiple parts to separate, and the single part (the condition) is required.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then putting semicolon repeatedly does not do any operation?

Comment: Nope. ...............

Comment: `;` is not an operator.

Comment: `;` is not an operator in C. It appears in the grammar in several places: The end of an expression statement (and the expression in an expression statement is optional, which is why `;` by itself is a valid statement), the end of a declaration (but not a function definition), the end of a jump statement (`goto`, `continue`, `break`, or `return`), the end of a `do`-`while` statement, and inside the parentheses of `for` statements.

Comment: Re “Then putting semicolon repeatedly does not do any operation?”: Stray semicolons can have deleterious effects. `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++); { statements… }` will not execute the statements in a loop because the `;` acts as a null statement for the `for` loop, leaving `{ statements… }` to stand on its own as a simple block that is executed once, not in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;` is not an operator, it is a punctuator that appears in various places in the language syntax. It may not appear arbitrary, but only in certain places specified by the formal syntax:

- As a punctuator symbol inside a string literal or character constant. Example: `";"`.
- At the end of a declaration or struct declaration. Example: `int a;`.
- At the end of an expression statement. Example `a=b;`.
  This includes (6.8.3)

  > A *null statement* (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.
- At the end of a `Static_assert`. Example `_Static_assert(foo==bar, "foobar");`.
- At the end of a do-while statement. Example `do(x) while(y) ;`.
- Separating the three clauses of a `for` statement. Example: `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`.
- After a jump statement. Example `return 0;`.

---

The `for` loop is a bit of a special snowflake since it allows these two cases of formal grammar (6.8.5):

> `for (` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;`*expression<sub>opt</sub>* `)` *statement*
> `for (` *declaration expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `)` *statement*

Where <sub>opt</sub> means optional. Note that a declaration expression will contain a `;` at the end, so it ends up with 2 of them no matter which version you pick.

Further, 6.8.5.3 states that the 1st and 3rd expressions are completely optional and can be omitted at any time. If the 2nd expression is omitted, it is however replaced by a non-zero constant, creating an eternal ("for ever") loop.

Normally such a loop is written as `for(;;) {}`.

---

Your examples are:

- 4 null statement expressions.
- An eternal `for(;;)` loop.
- A syntax error since the grammar for `while` is:

  > `while` `(` *expression* `)` *statement*.

  Where the expression is *not* optional.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, the correct way is as quoted. This is found below **Syntax** at 6.8.5.  6.8.5.3 makes a (normative) example where they name the expressions "clause-1", "expression-2" and "expression-3", but that isn't the formal syntax and I didn't feel a need to confuse the reader with different terms, why I didn't quote the text of that section.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So semicolon acts as statement terminator, not an operator.

Comment: @Emreİriş Rather, it acts as a reserved syntax item appearing in various well-defined places.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop with three 'empty' expressions (technically, the first is a *clause*) separated by the two semicolons works because each/any of those expressions is allowed to be omitted. From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.8.5.3 The for statement**
>  1 The statement
> **`for (`*clause-1* `;` *expression-2* `;` *expression-3* `)`** statement
>  behaves as follows ...
>  2  Both *clause-1*
> and *expression-3* can be omitted. An omitted *expression-2* is
> replaced by a nonzero constant.

However, the `while` statement does *not* allow the controlling expression (inside the parentheses) to be omitted. From the same draft standard (note there is no 'paragraph 2'):

> **6.8.5.1 The while statement**
>  1 The evaluation of the controlling expression takes place before each execution of the loop
> body

On the repeated use of the 'lone' semicolon(s) in your first code snippet: each of these delimits a *null statement*. Again, from the same draft standard:

> **6.8.3 Expression and null statements**
> ...
>  3 A *null statement* (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.

Null statements can be useful to define an 'empty' loop body; for example, the following code advances the `i` variable until a specific element in an array is found, but the loop itself doesn't have anything in the body:

```c
int i;
char array[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (i = 0; array[i] != 'q'; ++i)
    ; // The ";" forms a null statement as the loop's body

// After the loop, "i" will be the index of the letter q
```

Comment: this is good, but it misses to address the primary question in the question, use of empty `;`s.

Comment: Didn't I explain that already?  A semicolon is a *separator,* nothing more.   If you put several of them in succession, C merely ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to explain what does actually ; operator do in C and
> why it does not give an error when it is put nothing before ;?

`;` is not an operator. It is a statement *terminator*, and, separately, it is part of the syntax of a `for` statement.

In its role as a statement terminator, `;` can terminate an empty statement.  C allows such statements, and specifies that they have no effect.  This has limited use for providing an empty body for loop statements, in cases where the important work is done in the loop-control clause, but it is not limited to that context.

Similarly, in a `for` statement, any or all of the three expressions in the control clause are allowed to be omitted, but in that case the `;` is still required to show which those are.  If the controlling expression is omitted, then, by rule, it is treated as if it were a non-zero constant expression (that is, it is unconditionally truthy).  That should be considered a special case.  If the other expressions are omitted then simply no expression is evaluated at the corresponding points in the execution of the loop.

The rules for `while` statements, on the other hand, do not provide for the control expression to be omitted.  The bottom line is that that's simply the rule.